# SQL: Duplicate columns from join query

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a table purchase which is

### purchase_id   distributor_code  address

1                  12           xyz

2                  13           abc

another table purchase_item which has

### purchase_id  item_name

1              car

1              bike

i want to make a bill of item in which info from purchase table and purchase_item table should be shown for a given purchase_id...
Required:::

purchase_id=1,distributor_code=12,address=xyz,itemname=car,bike....

in my query distributor_code and address are getting repeated twice as there are 2 itemnames in purchase_item table for purchase_id=1...i have tried using outer join...please help!

Answer (score 0):

```
Select P.purchase_id
    , P.distributor_code
    , P.address
    , Stuff(
        (
        Select ', ' + Item.item_name
        From purchase_item As Item
        Where Item.purchase_id = P.purchase_id
        Order By Item.item_name
        For Xml Path(''), type
        ).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 2, '') As Items
From purchase As P
```